# Get custom field value in woocommerce_checkout_create_order hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

What am I doing wrong with this code? I am not able to retrieve the post_meta value. I know it is saved correctly because the values are displayed in the order edit page. I am just not able to retrieve in this function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'rev_change_total_on_checkout', 20, 1 );

function rev_change_total_on_checkout( $order ) {
    $new_total_price = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_rev_fee_estimate', true);
    $order->set_total($new_total_price );
}
```

Basically, I am trying to change the total order value after the checkout is submitted based on the values programmatically generated in a custom field value I added to the checkout form. If I hardcode the value of $new_total_price, I am able to achieve this, so I know this function works. I only need to retrieve the saved value of the custom field to finish this.

Comment: Also there are two arguments for that action so change 1 to 2 like so:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'rev_change_total_on_checkout', 20, 2 );

Answer (score 1):

In think that `_rev_fee_estimate` is not saved to database yet in this hook as it's a custom field. So you can get anything related.

Instead you need to get the posted value. I will use  the key `_rev_fee_estimate` but it can be something else (you can check for it, inspecting the generated html code for this custom field on checkout page. The necessary key is the attribute "name" value in this field)…

The code:

```
// Save an additional coverstart value in in the order post meta dat
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'initial_coverstart_custom_field_save', 20, 1 );
function initial_coverstart_custom_field_save( $order ) {
    if( ! isset($_POST['_rev_fee_estimate']) ) return;

    if( ! empty($_POST['_rev_fee_estimate']) )
    {
        $new_total_price = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_rev_fee_estimate'] )
        $order->set_total( $new_total_price );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work once you will have checked that you have the correct key for this custom field.